# How can I do an UPDATE statement with JOIN in JPQL (Spring JPA Queries)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, jpql

This is an extension of this question [Update Statement with JOIN in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql) but I am trying to use  Spring Data JPQL.

I am trying to use Update along with JOIN in JPQL as follows

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE TotalValue tv JOIN LineItems li WHERE li.totalValue.totalValueId=:totalValuedId SET tv.totalAmount =sum(li.itemTotalValue) ")
void calculateTotalAmount(@Param("totalValuedId") Long totalValuedId);
```

However, i get an error as follows

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting "set", found 'JOIN'

Is UPDATE and JOIN not possible in JPQL ? What is the alternative. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [JPQL syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html) seems to indicate that a JOIN is actually not possible in an UPDATE statement.

Comment: Many Thanks. I suspected as much. Is the alternative only a native query ?

Comment: Often it is possible to formulate the update without an explicit join, just with property navigation, but I'd need to see the relevant part of the entities to be sure. Otherwise, yes I think a native query would be applicable.

Comment: Thanks for your help.